# Динамический список, с разделителями. Android

Tags: android

Здравствуйте. Хочу реализовать динамический список, который будет формироватся из различных данных, и делится на группы. Возможно кто то видел пример реализации списка, как например на скрине: http://i.piccy.info/i7/769e4e8675abf32e2bf21900f9a06251/4-56-795/42783036/123123.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.pvsm.ru/android/14184/print/

Comment: Спасибо. То что нужно!

Answer (score 0):

Сам такой практики не имел, но почему просто динамически не определять разные стили полям? Создать контейнер, умную функцию работы с таким контейнером: например внутри N контейнеров, на вход принимает выборку нужного контейнера и добавляет запись, а на выход дает общий, каждая заглавная запись контейнера представляется соответствующим стилем - а уже этот конечный контейнер обрабатывать адаптером и выводиться в лист.

Если практически решения не найдешь, то я в понедельник попробую описать в коде. А сейчас выходные =)))

Comment: Мне вариант выше понравился. Хотелось вид как в Настройках, собственно, там такой и описан)
Но И Вам спасибо.)

Answer (score 0):

Есть библиотека от Hannes Dorfman, AdapterDelegate, очень удобная, даже если все элементы списка будут абсолютно разными:
https://github.com/sockeqwe/AdapterDelegates